# Added mime types to httpd.conf but still not loading video (gave up)

Tags: apache, types, mime-types, mime, httpd.conf

Hey I'm trying to get HTML5 video working on this page:
https://www.thankyoupayroll.co.nz/system-update_test.html

I've added these Mime types to the httpd.conf file and restarted the server:

```
AddType audio/mpeg .mp3
AddType audio/mp4 .m4a
AddType audio/ogg .ogg
AddType audio/ogg .oga
AddType audio/webm .webma
AddType audio/wav .wav

AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/mp4 .m4v
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/webm .webm
AddType video/webm .webmv
```

But in Firefox etc I'm still getting:
no video with supported format and mime type found

What else could be preventing the video from working?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The web server is refusing to send the video files.

Comment: Yeah, they work in internet explorer.  I ran firefox through a proxy, and it said that the server returned no response.  No headers, no body, it just closed the connection.

Comment: Interesting. Sorry but what is that telling us you think?

Comment: I'm stumped to be honest.  It must be something that firefox is sending in the headers that the webserver isn't liking, but I am unsure as to what it might be.  I can change the source on your page to point to a .mp4 file on another server, and it loads it just fine.  Your site being https only isn't making things easier either.  It definitely makes it more difficult to spoof requests to see what the problem part might be. (I don't have the greatest https tools)

Comment: Thanks man. A non https version of the page here: www.thankyoupayroll.co.nz/system-update.html Not sure what the proxy issue has to do with it. None of the pages on the site load via Firefox proxy for me. This isn't a problem for us generally.

Comment: Interesting.  Firefox is requesting the data from byte 0 on (HTTP HEADER `Range: bytes=0-` and that is causing it to fail.  If I remove that header from the firefox request, it works.  IE does not supply that header if it is asking for the data from the beginning, so it is not failing.

Comment: I am going to go out on a limb here and say you are running plesk on centos, and plesk probably put in a filter on request ranges to mitigate some old denial of service techniques and they put an improper regex in that causes `Range: bytes=0-` to fail.

Comment: Check in your httpd.conf for any rewrite rules that look similar to `HTTP:range`

Comment: Nope nothing I could see. I've given up and gone back to flash for now. Thanks for your help.